# KEYCLOAK not changing the idle time when using keycloak.protect()

Tags: javascript, node.js, keycloak

I am trying to implement keycloak in my application everything is working fine except the configuration for idle time if I set my idle time to 2 mins and max sso timeout to 4 min (for testing) my application is getting logged out in 2 mins only. Even if I am calling "Keycloak.protect()" method on each and every api call.

According to the docs "The idle time is refreshed with every action against the keycloak server for that session, i.e.: a user login, SSO, a refresh token grant, etc."

And I have read that keycloak.protect() does the authentication for user login.But it is not working in my code.

Can any 1 please help me on how can i refresh the idle time on each api hit on my application.

Comment: Same here, calling `protection()` and `entitlement()` directly via an Authz Client, seems SSO idle time is not prolonged after that.

Comment: In the latest version they say:
`How is idle time checked? A client requesting authentication will bump the idle timeout. Refresh token requests will also bump the idle timeout.`